# How to set sequence starting value in EF6 code first?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6

I'm using PostgresSQL in EF6 project with code first approach and need to set starting value of an Identity column that is primary key as well.
Probably it can not be done through annotation how can I do it through code?
Tried to override OnModelCreaing with:

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT setval('MySchema.\"MyDataSources_Id_seq\"', 1001, true)");
```

but it says:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created.
> This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
> OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
> multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
> and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Any help?